# X is a binomial (n=4,p=1/3) random variable. Let Y=2X-1.

Tags: probability

X is a binomial (n=4,p=1/3) random variable. Let Y=2X-1. 
Find E(Y).

E= np but not sure how to get E(2X-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the linearity of expectation to write
$$
EY=2(EX)-1
$$